# Passing a structure as a char buffer to a proc entry

Tags: c++, c, linux, data-structures, character-encoding

I want to pass a character buffer to a proc entry (say /proc/my_file) from my program. This character buffer contains my structure's elements which is of the form:

```
struct my_table { char src_ip[4]; char dest_ip[4]; int out_flag; }my_t;
```

I assign the elements of my_table and copy its contents to an unsigned char buffer as follows:

```
memcpy(buffer, &my_t, sizeof(struct my_table));
```

Then I write the buffer's contents into a proc entry created by me (by the name my_file) as:

```
write(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

where fd is the file descriptor returned by open() after opening the /proc/my_file with O_WRONLY | O_APPEND flags.

What I couldn't understand is that I can only see the first character string i.e my_t.src_ip in this case to be written to /proc/my_file (did a

> cat /proc/my_file

to check the content written) and subsequently I observed that the write() operation to /proc/my_file ends as soon as it encounters a null character in the buffer content.

Can I know why does this happen and how to solve this problem of writing a structure's contents into a /proc entry?

Edit: SSCCE for my question:
The structure:

```
struct my_iptable { 
    char protocol[5];                   // to check whether the protocol mentioned is tcp/udp/icmp 
    char src_ip[16];                    // source ip address
    char dest_ip[16];                   // destination ip address
    char src_net_mask[16];              // source net mask
    char dest_net_mask[16];             // destination net mask
    int src_port;                       // source port number
    int dest_port;                      // destination port number
    char action[8];                     // either block or unblock
    int delete_rule;                    // gets the rule number to be deleted
    int print_flag;                     // is set if we are asked to print the rules that have been set         
    int out_flag;                       // is set if the packet is outbound, else set to 0;
};
```

The assignment of my_ipt to null:

struct my_iptable my_ipt;
memset(&my_ipt, '\0', sizeof(struct my_iptable));

I have assigned my_ipt's fields properly.

The copying to buffer and writing to proc part:

```
unsigned char write_buf[sizeof(struct my_iptable)];     
    memcpy(write_buf, &my_ipt, sizeof(struct my_iptable));
int proc_fp = open("/proc/minifw", O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);
    if(proc_fp < 0) {
        printf("Couldn't open /proc/minifw for writing\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}

   if(write(proc_fp, write_buf, sizeof(struct my_iptable)) == -1) {
        printf("There was an error writing to minifw buffer\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

I hope this gives you appropriate info on what I want to understand.

Thanks!

Comment: Whu not `write(fd, &my_t, sizeof(struct my_table))` directly ?..

Comment: Hi @xtofpernaud, I did that too, but couldn't get what I expected.
Also, I have declared my buffer as unsigned char buffer[sizeof(struct my_table)]

Comment: I think you'll need to produce an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) if you want more specific answers to this question.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue, have edited my question as you have asked.

Comment: @freax: No, you haven't. You're fired!

Comment: @freax: Is this compilable? Let's say I copy and paste it into my editor, hit compile... You know? No. It's not compilable. Where's your main? Where are your includes? Read [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) again and focus upon the "correct (compilable)" attribute.

Answer (score 3):

use `sizeof(struct my_table)` instead

```
write(fd, buffer, sizeof(struct my_table));
```

If your `buffer` is defined as pointer:

```
struct my_table *buffer;
```

then the size of `buffer` will be equal to the size of pointer (4 for 32-bit systems and 8 for 64-bit systems) and not the real size of the `struct my_table`

Comment: It'd be nice to be able to program without *buffers*... "Shine your shoes, guvnah?"

Comment: @modifiablelvalue I did not understand your answer but if you are addressing to the OP then put your comment on his question